# How reuse __str__ function in models.py for each class model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

Hello everyone I start use Django Framework and I have a question.

Django's documentation says, when I create class(model) in the end of class I should write function to return string value for my object, it all look like this:

```
class NameClass(models.Model):
    field_name_1 = models.SomeTypeField()
    field_name_2 = models.SomeTypeField()
    field_name_3 = models.SomeTypeField()
    ...
    field_name_n =  models.SomeTypeField() 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.field_name_1, ...self.field_name_n
```

In this case I wrote function for return string value, cause I have a lot of fields in my models and write each of them in `__str__` function it will be a lot of work. So my function look like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    fields =''
    for x in self._meta.fields:
        fields = fields + string.split(str(x),".")[2]+' '
    return fields
```

Now question. How can I reuse this function in each class(model) in model.py, without copy paste this function?

For example. I have a lot of classes(mdoels):

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        ...
class SecondModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        ...

class ThirdModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        ... 
class EtcModel(models.Model):
    ....
    def __str__(self):
```

And I don't want copy paste my function everytime, may exist some way to use it like a global function or another way to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use inheritance (inherit your different classes from one base class that provides the `__str__` method you want).

Or if that doesn't work for you, and you just want to share this method implementation in the easiest way possible, you can assign methods in your classes instead of defining them.

```
def mystrfunction(self):
   return whatever

class Class1(object):
   ...
   __str__ = mystrfunction

class Class2(object):
   ...
   __str__ = mystrfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside, define a function,

```
def foo(obj):
    fields =''
    for x in obj._meta.fields:
        fields = fields + string.split(str(x),".")[2]+' '
    return fields
```

Inside the class,

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    ...
    __str__ = foo
```

Comment: I used a redundant version. Similar to `if (a==b) return true; else return false;`

Comment: @downvoter it was not wrong though `def __str__(self): return foo(self)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your classes only share the same methods you can use a mixin:

```
class BaseMixin(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.something

class Foo(BaseMixin, models.Model):
    # ...
```

For all models that share the same fields and methods, you can create a [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) Eg:

```
class Base(models.Model):
  class Meta:
      abstract = True
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title


class Foo(Base):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance:

```
class MyBaseModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        ...
class FirstModel(MyBaseModel):
    ...
class SecondModel(MyBaseModel):
    ...
    def __str__(self):  # you can adjust the inherited method 
        retval = super().__str__()
        return retval + ' ' + self.fld10
```